# Generating an executable file from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, executable, executable-jar

I've made a program to help me out with some stuff, but every time I need it, I open Eclipse and Run it.

Is it possible to create an executable file so I won't need to open Eclipse every time?
The commands I use is basically System.out.println() and Scanner to read what I type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right-click on project.
Export as runnable jar.

Comment: Don't forget to choose the right `Main` file (or `StartUp` or whatever you called it).

Answer (score 4):

`File -> Export -> Java -> Runnable JAR File`

You'll have to choose the main class that you want it to run.  This will allow you to double-click on the JAR, and have it run that main.

Answer (score 0):

You can `File > Export > JAR file` to export your project as a jar and put the java command to run the jar on a windows batch file. Alternatively you can `File > Export > Runnable JAR file`

Answer (score 0):

You can either create an executable jar file (using eclipse, or a build tool like "ant" or "maven") or you can also create a "real" Windows-executable file (which you can also give to customers/friends).

I am using JSmooth a lot ( http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/ ) - this builds a wrapper around your jar-files and can help the user with downloading and installing an appropriate java virtual machine version.

Probably the executable jar (see answer of Serplat) file is what you need :)